# tinymce: rich text mode, how does it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, text-editor

I want to understand how tinymce functions.

the rich text editor contains an html document within an iframe. how are the nested DOM elements inside editable, In other word how am I able to type inside a `<div>` or a `<p>` layer when there is no textarea or input field involved (at least I dont see any)?

are the elements converted to input fields when they are active?

edit: If your going to vote down the question, please state why.

Comment: An answer to your question is way beyond the scope of SO. You could try TinyMCE's forum: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/ Asking for thousands of lines of code to be condensed into a post that fits in a forum is still pretty broad, though.

Comment: Voting up! Good question. I was looking for the same answer. As I understand the question (and what I need), we don't care about tinymce, just need to understand the mechanism to reuse it in our own solutions. This is exactly what SO for :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In tinyMCE's case (and most other editors) it's an `<iframe>` (as to not inherit styling from the parent page, among other reasons), but the magic is the [`contentEditable` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.contentEditable) being set to `true`.

[You can read more detail in the working draft of HTML5 here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable).

[You can test a very simplified demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Gq6dr/), the editors do much more of course with their toolbars, a backing `<textarea>` to store the markup for server-submission, etc...but your question seems to be how are you editing the elements, the core of that is [`contenteditable`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-contenteditable).

Comment: Oh my gush!!! It's SO SIMPLE! I can't believe! Just one attribute. I was under impression that it should be some tricky JavaScript which monitor textarea changes and change html accordingly (like create <p> and set styling one the flight.)... omg! really, can't believe... you open my eyes!